# Microsoft Exchange 2007, Small Business Server, Delegate Accounts

Tags: exchange, small-business

We have exchange running on one of our server here and there are 2 users connecting via outlook. The company has a generic Info@ email account and all users need to see this. I know I cant add a second exchange account to outlook so what are my options? Every user needs to see whats not been read whats been responded to etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically three options:

- A distribution list (each user gets a copy, no "real" sharing).
- A mail-enabled public folder (the folder receives messages, users read them, they reply with their own address).
- A shared mailbox (a true Exchange mailbox, you open it as a secondary mailbox in Outlook).

I strongly recommend the shared mailbox. You create it like any other standard mailbox (it needs its own AD user account, but you can safely disable it), then you set permissions on it to allow other users to open it and send messages using its address. In Outlook, you can open it as a secondary mailbox besides your main one (if you have rights on it, of course).

Comment: @Massimo Outlook only seems to support 1 exchange box can you expand on this?

Comment: You can only have a single Exchange account, but you can open additional mailboxes if you have the proper access rights. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP010030561033.aspx